# Dynamically exclude certain attributes during gson serialization (Java)

Tags: java, gson

Is there a way to dynamically exclude certain attributes of a class during gson serialization? (Based on a parameter I pass to the writer)

Or should I make 2 different serializers?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think you can do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `transient` attribute. Ex:
`private transient String name;`

Also you can add this property

`Gson gson = gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT).create();`

Edit: Take a look [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-builder-exclusion-strategies)

Comment: I know how to use `transient` but that's not what I'm looking for. I'll edit my question with an example to make it clearer.

Comment: Hmm, but I want to exclude the fields based on a parameter I pass to serializer (something like "forDebug"). So maybe I could exclude fields with transient modifier only if my boolean is set to True, right?

Comment: Create new class that implemets `ExclusionStrategy` and pass what you want in constructor, eg. 'foDebug" boolean and exclude fields using that param.